# SSH terminal automatic resizing

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal, resize

Ubuntu installations (12.04 and 14.04) from the mini.iso (and not on Server or Desktop versions) result in the host providing terminal session that do not automatically resize themselves to the same size of the client when one SSHs into them. This can be seen below:

[image]

This is noticeable on Rackspace cloud Ubuntu servers as well as KVM instances that I have deployed myself.

One can workaround the issue by installing `xterm` and running the command `resize` manually every time you resize your terminal.

Does anybody know what packages I need to install/configure to have the host act like the Server and Desktop installations whereby there is automatic adjustment?

---

**Update**

I discovered that for my local KVM setup, I only got this effect when connecting with `sudo virsh console $VM_ID` and not when I SSH into the virtual machine. However this problem still persists with Rackspace VMs. I just tried again today (25th May 2014) and easily noticeable when you open VIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SSH doesn't resize terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/680454/ssh-doesnt-resize-terminal). The user reported that the problem was fixed when he upgraded to gnome-terminal-3.12.1.

To install the new version in 14.04:

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte3/libvte-2.90-common_0.36.2-1ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte3/libvte-2.90-9_0.36.2-1ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-data_3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal_3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libvte-2.90-common_0.36.2-1ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb
dpkg -i libvte-2.90-9_0.36.2-1ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i gnome-terminal-data_3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb
dpkg -i gnome-terminal_3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
```

And to uninstall (change the versions to match the latest found in the archive.ubuntu.com repository):

```
# apt-cache madison gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data libvte-2.90 libvte-2.90-common
gnome-terminal | 3.6.2-0ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
gnome-terminal | 3.6.2-0ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Sources
gnome-terminal-data | 3.6.2-0ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
gnome-terminal | 3.6.2-0ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Sources
libvte-2.90-dev | 1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libvte-2.90-9 | 1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libvte-2.90-doc | 1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libvte-2.90-common | 1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libvte-2.90-common | 1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
      vte3 | 1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Sources
# apt-get install gnome-terminal=3.6.2-0ubuntu1 gnome-terminal-data=3.6.2-0ubuntu1 libvte-2.90-9=1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 libvte-2.90-common=1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data libvte-2.90-9 libvte-2.90-common
```

Comment: How does one get gnome terminal 3.12.1. I tried installing ubuntu gnome 14 in a VB and I still only get to 3.6. Is there a PPA?

Comment: It is in the [Gnome 3 Staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging). Be warned that enabling that PPA might pull in a lot of untested packages.

Comment: wow yes that works (tested in VB)! Now if anyone can tell me how I can pull a later version of gnome-terminal without adding the `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging` ppa and pulling down a bunch of other packages and making my system a lot less stable....

Comment: Install instructions in answer.

Comment: sorry for the long delay, just tested and works. Thanks!. Have given the bounty. Any chance of a quick addition to provide the necessary command(s) to revert the change if later desired?

Comment: Uninstall instructions added.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/562848/ubuntuterminalsshvim-resize) on SU, the comments on it may help, if they don't you may be stuck. Here was the last comment in particular:

> Try $ echo $COLUMNS and $ echo $LINES in the big window and the
>   smaller one to see if your terminal actually notices that it's resized

Comment: Yes outputting $COLUMNS does indeed show that it is set to 80 and not auto resizing. You have to manually run 'resize' in the terminal for it to auto resize to the correct number. Why is this not happening automatically?

Comment: Maybe take a look here and see if any of the [answers this guy suggested worked](http://serverfault.com/a/452710). Specifically I think he is replacing bash with tsch (sorry my knowledge on the topic isn't that great).

I know its a pain but why not run ! resize from the terminal? do you resize a lot?

Comment: Installing tcsh, restarting sshd, and reconnecting just resulted in using a shell other than bash when logging in. Bash still has the same problems, and tcsh just has other wierd effects. Text will go to the full width of the window but once you wrap, it appears you cannot backspace to the first line. Vi terminal still stays at 80 cols.

Comment: I am truly lost for ideas. Next best is to have that command constantly running in the background I guess.

Comment: Check [out this Unix/Linux StackExchange answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283206/163362) for a script-based solution as well.